# Deep recursion while using Mojolicious bridges

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious bridge defined

```
my $foo = $route->bridge('/')->to(cb => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    return 1;
});
return $foo;
```

and I am defining routes like this

```
$foo->route('/')->to(
    module      => 'test',
    controller  => 'test',
    action      => 'test'
);

$foo->route('/login')->to(
    module      => 'test1',
    controller  => 'test1',
    action      => 'test1'
);
```

Once I start the app, get a error
Deep recursion on subroutine "Mojolicious::Routes::Route::AUTOLOAD" at /usr/local/share/perl5/Mojolicious/Routes/Route.pm line 23.

I have no clue what is happening here. Can anyone help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do is redefine the AUTOLOAD sub to cluck a trace, like so:

```
{   no warnings 'redefine';
    my $old_autoload = *Mojolicious::Routes::Route::AUTOLOAD{CODE};
    *Mojolicious::Routes::Route = sub { 
        Carp::cluck( "Trace from $Mojolicious::Routes::Route::AUTOLOAD\n - " );
        goto &$old_autoload;
    };
}
```

This will at least give you the name and path of the problem. You could also put some recursion tracking in there, although it might need to mess up the small footprint a `goto` leaves behind.

Comment: @MojoUser, sometime before the code that blows up. If you don't know what code that is, then `say` things like `'route / set up.'` after each successful step.

Comment: Thank you. It's trying to call method shortcuts on Mojolicious:Routes:Route